# Typogrify equivalent for .NET

Tags: .net, python, django, assemblies, typography

Does anyone know of, or use a library that has similar functionality to Typogrify ([http://code.google.com/p/typogrify](http://code.google.com/p/typogrify/)/) in a .NET project. Typogrify is a Python/Django library and I am looking for an equivalent that I could use in a .NET project.

*Edit: Now I'm just looking for any typography processing library for .NET*

Answer (score 0):

[Textile](http://textilenet.codeplex.com/) has some of the same function

> Textile.NET is, surprisingly, a textile formatter for .NET projects.
>   Textile is a "human web text generator"
>   (http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/) that is useful for rapid web
>   writings such as Wiki syntax or blog articles. From a simple and
>   intuitive syntax it creates well formed HTML with advanced formatting
>   features, while also allowing the user to customize the output.

Comment: Seems overkill for functionality as I'm already using Markdown.